# How to compare two datasets and flag rule violation

Tags: alteryx

Been stuck on this problem for a while now. I am not able to think through the logic and implementation using Alteryx to achieve the desired results.

There's two data sets, given below-

Data set 1

```
Risk ID     Rule ID     Code
FR01        00Q         FBREV
FR01        00Q         FBREV1
FR01        00Q         FBREV2
FR02        02D         FBREV
FR02        02D         FBREV12
```

The combination of risk and rule ID in the first data set leads to the unique list of codes.

Data set 2

```
Column1     Code
User1       FBREV
User1       FBREV1
User2       FBREV
```

Users are tagged with codes that they use.

When they use codes that are in the same Risk and Rule ID family, it is a violation.

I just want to be able to flag those users who have violated this rule.

In the above data sets, User1 has violated the rule as he used two codes (FBREV and FBREV1). Both of the codes fall under the (FR01+ 00Q) rule. Hence I need to be able to tag User1 as a rule violator. User2 is not a rule violator as he did not use code (FBOPO).

I have been breaking my head over this for a few days now.

Comment: In data set 1, you have "FBREV" beside both FR01 and FR02, so your list is not exactly unique. It's also unclear how you achieve "FBREV" at all, given "FR01" and "00Q" .... wouldn't it be "FR0100Q"?  If so, then Degan's solution is spot on. If not, we need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to group together the unique RiskID/RuleIDs under which the codes used by the users fall, then find where a users has more than one of the same RiskID/RuleID combinations.

[image: Alteryx workflow]

The top text input is Data Set 1, the bottom text input is Data Set 2
The Formula concatenates the RiskID and RuleID:

```
[Risk ID] + [Rule ID]
```

The join is on Code

Summarize grouping by Risk&RuleID and Field1 (the user) and get a count of each Risk&RuleID:

[image: Summarize actions]

Finally, filter those users who have a count of the same Risk&RuleID greater than 1

Output (true):

> User1